# Boost priority queue comparison function

Tags: c++, boost, comparison

How to change comparison function on a priority queue with boost library?
I have a struct like this :

```
struct decreasingOrderMyType
{
    bool operator() (const MyType & lhs, const MyType & rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.value > rhs.value;
    }
};
```

and i would like use it to compare my elements.

thanks!

Comment: The first parameter to the explicit constructor is a user-specified comparator.

Comment: @ReubenMorais - that shoud be an answer :) `explicit priority_queue(value_compare const & = value_compare());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the std::priority_queue I have it specified as: `std::priority_queue<DistanceTuple, std::vector<DistanceTuple>, SmallestOnTop > pq;`

`DistanceTuple` is a `std::pair` and `SmallestOnTop` is a functor to compare the `std::pair`

**Update:** I was wrong, they are not identical. The boost version uses named parameters. Which work like this:

```
boost::heap::priority_queue<MyType,
                            boost::heap::compare<decreasingOrderMyType> > pq;
```